# Multiple eclipse profiles

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, profile, workspace

What's the simplest way to run multiple, completely separate Eclipse profiles?

I have some projects that use google appengine, some android projects, and some standard Java projects. I'd like to keep these three separate, as the app engine and android projects require extensive plugins to be installed that slow Eclipse down and interfere with other functions.

I've tried creating a different workspace for each, but when I e.g. install the android plugin in one workspace it shows up in the others. I believe this is because it adds data to

`$HOME/.eclipse`

So, what's the easiest/nicest way to run three *truly* separate profiles?

Comment: Maybe some solution based on the **Locations** section of [this document](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create 3 different eclipse installations. (different directories for each installation)

Comment: I also thought the same but it is not the best option but a good option.

Comment: Yes, I'm also interested why is this not the best option? AFAIK the Android plugin installation alters the eclipse environment in a way that is not recommended to work with for regular Java projects so a different installation is a must.

Comment: How will three different Eclipse installations help me? The problem plugin data appears to be stored in `$HOME/.eclipse`.

Comment: Maybe the data for the plugins is there but the pluguins themselves reside in the <eclipse_installation>/plugin directory of each installation. I got 2 seperate installations on my machine, one for developing Android and the other for regular Java and it works fine.

Comment: Eclipse stores plugins in $HOME/.eclipse if your main installation area is read-only (as it would be for the eclipse that comes with a linux distro).

Comment: chown'ing the Eclipse installation directory to my user fixed this. Thanks Paul!

Answer (score 4):

You can create 3 installs with a shared bundle pool (all of the common eclipse plugins shared).  Then installing into each individual eclipse install keeps the plugins separate.  ex, if `PROF=basicEclipse` and `TARGET=/an/absolute/path`

```
eclipse/eclipse \
-application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
-noSplash -bundlepool $TARGET -shared $TARGET/p2 \
-destination $TARGET/$PROF \
-profile SDKProfile_$PROF \
-profileProperties org.eclipse.update.install.features=true \
-p2.os linux -p2.ws gtk -p2.arch x86_64 -roaming \
-repository http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6 \
-installIUs org.eclipse.sdk.ide
```

you can launch that eclipse install with `$TARGET/basicEclipse/eclipse`.  Running it again with `PROF=androidEclipse` creates $TARGET/andoidEclipse with the executables, but shares most of the common eclipse plugins (in the $TARGET directory).  I had to use Eclipse 3.7 M7 to run the director app correctly, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342156

However ... unless you're short of disk-space, it seems that simply untarring an install 3 times will be a simpler way to separate your install :-)

Comment: Nice. I thought there must be a way to achieve this using args of this kind - thanks for taking the time to document this approach! Agreed though, untarring 3 times is much simpler right now.

Answer (score 2):

As Paul Webster already noted, if your Eclipse installation is read only, Eclipse will store plugin data in your home directory. The Eclipse Platform Manual [refers to](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/multi_user_installs.html) this concept as *Install area* which *can be read only*. In a single user installation, the *Install area* is merged with the *Configuration area* which is the directory in which caches, configuration and plugin data is stored.

To enable multi user installations, you can either create a shared configuration which is like a base for your other environments. Or you can create completely separate configuration areas which share no common settings but use the same install area hence saving space on your hard drive.

There is no GUI in Eclipse to easily set these things up though. For the necessary command line switches refer to the [Eclipse Platform Manual](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/multi_user_installs.html).

I have also created a Python script that lets you implement and switch between completely separate configuration areas with a nice GUI. You can install it with `pip install eclipseprofileselector` or check out the code [from my github repository](https://github.com/privatwolke/eclipseprofileselector).

Answer (score 0):

You could use different OS profiles each with its own workspace or just different installations of Eclipse?  I wish I knew a better answer myself but I personally get aggravated when Eclipse plugins operate outside of their designated workspace like this.